# ruby: jsonpath accessing with if case

Tags: ruby, jsonpath

I have a following json. With a jsonpath gem I can access child events via

```
JsonPath.new("$.child_events[*]").on(b)
```

However, I need to check if in child_events there is a "via_reference_id".

```
JsonPath.new("$[?(@.child_events[*].via_reference_id)].ticket_id").on(b)
```

But this does not work. How can I access ticket_id only if there is a 'via_reference_id" in any of the child_events?

```
b = {"created_at"=>"2016-12-12T23:03:45Z", "ticket_id"=>24510, "timestamp"=>1481583825, "event_type"=>"Audit", "system"=>{"longitude"=>nil, "location"=>nil, "client"=>nil, "latitude"=>nil}, "id"=>110084880989, "updater_id"=>7964288149, "via"=>"Web form", "child_events"=>[{"event_type"=>"Change", "previous_value"=>"offered", "id"=>110084881029, "via_reference_id"=>nil, "satisfaction_score"=>"good", "via"=>"Web form"}, {"status"=>"open", "event_type"=>"Change", "via"=>"Rule", "id"=>110084881109, "via_reference_id"=>46315149, "rel"=>"trigger", "previous_value"=>"solved"}]}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @WayneConrad it throws an error `SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected ']'`